# Single configuration for multiple projects with MSBuild?

Tags: configuration, msbuild, external

i am looking for possibility of building with MSBuild in a way, where i can use one configuration for multiple projects.

Here is configuration i want to share:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <MySourceFiles Include="$(TargetDir)\*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Prepare" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Message Text="Preparing folders..." Importance="high" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(SolutionDir)Build\$(Configuration)" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(SolutionDir)Build\$(Configuration)\Plugins" />
    <Message Text="Folders prepared..." Importance="high" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="$(AssemblyName) - Copying output" Importance="high" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(SolutionDir)Build\$(Configuration)" SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
    <Message Text="$(AssemblyName) - Copying finished" Importance="high" />
  </Target>
```

As you can see. It will simply check/create *Build/Debug* folder and copy all compiled files there. And this i need for multiple projects.

Is this possible to have in some external xml or proj file and load configuration and load it from there? I want to prevent possible problems with updates in future.

Thanks for help

Comment: Just `<Import Project="myProj.targets">` in every project, where myProj.targets conatins the code shown ? - though I think you're better of not using SolutionDir but ProjectDir etc, not all projects have a solution

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what i need. How to mark your comment as answer?

Comment: you can't - I'll add it as an actual answer then you can accept that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
<Import Project="myProj.targets">
```

in every project, where myProj.targets contains the code as you show.
However it is probably better to refer to `ProjectDir` and the likes instead of `SolutionDir` since not all projects have a corresponding solution, and even if they do you might want to use them as if they do not. Anyway, that way your project is self-contained and does not need a solution.